# Start token in window word embeddings

Tags: neural-network, nlp, nltk, lstm, named-entity-recognition

I'm using the pre-trained SENNA embeddings and feeding a 3 word window into a Dense neural net.

Does senna have a start or end token embedding? 
Or do I create a random vector?

```
Sentence:  'McDonalds sells fries'
input 1:  ['<s>', 'McDonalds', 'sells']
```

But there is no embedding for `<s>`... 
Do I create my own? (all -1 for example)?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the main page on https://ronan.collobert.com/senna/ it seems tokenisation and (which would include special sentence boundary tokens) are taking care of internally.

Is there a reason why you want to include them?
From the site, they seem implicit on input context ( single sentence ).

Taken from the website:

```
Usage

SENNA reads input sentences from the standard input 
and outputs tags into the standard output. 
The most likely command line usage for SENNA is therefore:

senna [options] < input.txt > output.txt

Of course you can run SENNA in an interactive mode 
without the "pipes" < and >.

Each input line is considered as a sentence. 
SENNA has its own tokenizer for separating words, 
which can be deactivated with the -usrtokens option.
```